# Java datatransfer through sockets. How to keep sender and receiver in "sync"

Tags: java, sockets, buffer

I want to implement a simple way to transfer Data from one client to another.
The implementation itself is not the question - it already works. I've a problem with the real transfer rate on sender side.

You all know the progress bars while you send files to another client using [put your desired chat/filetransfer program here]. You see the transferred bytes and the bytes left to transfer and maybe an estimated time until the transfer is complete. The same thing I try to implement too but it seems I've problems with the buffers in between.
While the send buffer is a nice feature - it affect the measured transfer rate to the other client enormously. Starting the transfer I get nearly infinite Bps and during the transfer the Bps reduce slowly but never get where the real transfer is.
The effect is that the sender visually finishes sending a file while the receiver still receiving bytes. This totally desync sender and receiver what I need to avoid (because of other reasons).

My first attempt sending a file was just like this (pseudo code):

```
while(still bytes left to read) {
    Sender reading Byte-Array from InputStream (aka FileInputStream or something else)
    Sender write and flushes this Byte-Array to the SocketOutputStream
}
```

This ends in the described situation where sender and receiver is totally desynced.

My next attempt was this:

```
while(still bytes left to read) {
    Sender reading Byte-Array from InputStream (aka FileInputStream or something else)
    Sender write and flushes this Byte-Array to the SocketOutputStream
    Sender wait for ACK-Paket from Receiver
}
```

So the sender write the Byte-Array to the wire and wait for a small ACK-Paket from the receiver. After receiving the ACK the sender sends the next Byte-Array.
While this works as desired on slow connections (aka WAN connections to the internet) it is horrible slow on LAN connections.
I came to the conclusion that I don't like the ACK-Idea but I also don't like the desync situation.
How does other clients workaround such situations? Is there a way to disable the buffer so that `outputStream.write(byte[])` just take as long as the wire need to transmit the data, or is there any other mechanism I can use to "see" how many bytes are transferred for real?

Thanks in advance

Martin

Comment: this is just how TCP works, you are wasting your time, there is buffering and other latency in the middle you will never be able to control or effect.

Comment: Just a moment. The objective isn't a nice synchronized display, the objective is to transfer the data, ASAP. You don't want to slow down or complicate your sending or receiving (e.g. via your ACK packet, or @PeterLawrey's suggestion) just to make your GUI look pretty. Rethink. I would just track the *input* to the send, e.g. the `FileInputStream.` NB you should never flush inside a loop.

Comment: @EJP: The suggested solution from PeterLawrey doesn't slow down the transfer itself. The Sender sends its data with one thread and receives the data in another Thread. So the data gets transferred ASAP.
Thanks for your other hint to not flush inside a loop. I'll act on your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of displaying what you have sent, display what the other end has told you it has received. i.e. the other end can send back the number of bytes it has received. This way your progress bar will be slightly pessimistic, rather than really optimistic.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I've implemented your mentioned 'update messages' from the receiver and displaying this information instead of senders own information. This way all works as expected!

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you are trying to send the entire array you managed to read as a single object. On the sending side, you get a big array, call `write` and then `flush` which sends the entire array and waits for it to be flushed (with no control for you in between, so you sending app has no way to display progress). On the receiving end you get the same problem. You probably just call `read` which would read the entire ArrayList in a single operation.

Chances are, you are able to read a lot of data before you try to send it as a big array.

You can get some control if you break the array into reasonable "chunks" (maybe a simple `max(1024, arraysize/100)`). Then send the chunks one by one. The pseudo code would look like this:

```
chunkSize = max(1024, arraysize/100)
while(still bytes left to read) {
    Sender reading chunkSize bytes into Byte-Array from InputStream
    Sender write and flushes this Byte-Array to the SocketOutputStream
    reportProgress()
}
```

Comment: The words `ArrayList` and `Object` do not appear in the OP's question.

Comment: apologies about the ArrayList (must have misread it as such). The rest of the answer is probably still valid (chances are the the OP is reading too big of a byte array and then sending it across via a writeObject call).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I already read the data in smaller blocks (chunks) and send these smaller blocks to the wire.